# Is it possible with PHP to find Programmatically a mail subdomain or url from an email address?

Tags: php, laravel-4

After a user create account, I plan on displaying a link to lead user to the mail server of his email.
For example :
if user1 has user1@gmail.com, the link would point towards gmail.com or mail.google.com.
if user2 has user2@yahoo.com the link would point towards mail.yahoo.com.

In PHP I can do

```
$domain = explode("@", 'user1@gmail.com')[1];
$domain2 = explode("@", 'user2@yahoo.com')[1];
$mailUrl = $domain; //will work
$mailUrl2 = $domain; //will not work
$mailUrl = 'mail.'.$domain; //will not work
$mailUrl2 = 'mail.'.$domain; // will work
```

So I cannot predict manually the submain structure. I was wondering if there is a PHP function or Laravel 4 package that returns me the proper subdomain for the email address like gmail.com, mail.google.com, mail.yahoo.com, hotmail.com, etc.

Comment: You cannot do this with a regular expression. In fact, I'd say you shouldn't do this at all. What are you trying to do here? Technically this is done via [MX records](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MX_record) and DNS but it's far from trivial.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Are you asking if there is a list of webmail domains that you can use to translate `@yahoo.com` into `mail.yahoo.com`?

Comment: I'm trying to facilitate some users of my Country (that do not seem to know that they have to verify their eamil after registration) to go directly to their email account and verify their newly created account.

Comment: @Pitchinnate, that would fit a lot if there is no automatic way.

Comment: Oh, this is impossible. You can make a look-up table for common ones, but even that is going to be absoulutely infuriating: Yahoo has *hundreds* of variant domains. Nobody publishes what their web interface to email is, and not everyone uses web email, many just use their phone, Outlook, or whatever.

Comment: It would be easiest just to have a message telling them to check their email and click on the confirmation link

Comment: Ok thanks for your quick response guys. I'm in Haiti, and trust if users dont make it with Android email, there is a huge chance that 50% dont verify their email after. I used Facebook Signup too which facilitate things. I can tell you that almost 50% of my people willing to use Facebook are using it because a friend created the account for them. The message idea seems great, and the webmail list would fit for the moment. Where can I find such a list? Even if it's not 100% accurate.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this using the PHP function  [getmxrr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getmxrr.php).

Here's a snippet:

```
<?php
    // Where the mx records will be added 
    $records = [];

    // Calling, change gmail.com to whatever you need
    getmxrr('gmail.com', $records);

    // dump the array's contents
    var_dump($records);
?>
```

Comment: This does not give you the address of their webmail, just their MX records, and I don't see how that helps.

Comment: The author mentioned "mail server of his email. " I though he meant the actual mx records.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. At least I learned the MX records function. But it gives multiple subs like mx4.hotmail.com for hotmail.com and subs like gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com for gmail.com. None of them will redirect you to gmail.com. Unless there is another function to that, it wont help.

Comment: Sorry @HenriqueB. for not being clear. I just want user to click a link that will lead him to login page of the webmail of his email address